# Python interactive plot in browser: drag and drop arbitrary elements

Tags: python, matplotlib, d3.js, plot, mpld3

I have my backend in Python and I'm trying to create an interactive plot in the web browser, where the user can drag and drop elements across the plot. The plan is then to hook onto the 'drop' event with some JS that updates values in a form and submits the form, which would then cause the backend to update the plot.

So far I have been using mpld3, but I am not invested in it. I would be open to a solution using some other package like Plotly or Bokeh.

What I am looking for is quite similar to [this mpld3 example](http://mpld3.github.io/examples/drag_points.html), except that I want to allow the user to drag objects other than the points. Specifically, I want to create some vertical and horizontal lines and allow the user to drag these horizontally and vertically, as illustrated in this picture:

[image]

I have gotten so far as to adapt the mpld3 plugin to actually work with the latest version of d3.js, and I am able to drag the points (see [gist](https://gist.github.com/tadamcz/d02c57f64a37e9aee45a3654cc83d245)). However, I am not able to adapt the plugin to make the vertical lines draggable like the points in the example.

My first idea was something like

```
lines = ax.vlines(xdata,min(ydata),ydata)
plugins.connect(fig, DragPlugin(lines))
```

`vlines()` returns a `matplotlib.collections.LineCollection` item, and I don't know how to access individual lines inside that. I tried simply modifying the type check inside the `__init__` (`if isinstance(object, mpl.lines.Line2D)` to be more permissive, but that didn't work.

My next idea was to just draw the lines using `ax.plot()`:

```
lines = []
for i in range(len(xdata)):
    from_xy = (xdata[i],min(ydata))
    to_xy = (xdata[i],ydata[i])
    xs = from_xy[0],to_xy[0]
    ys = from_xy[1],to_xy[1]
    lines.append(ax.plot(xs,ys, 'k-')[0])
```

In this case the list `lines` contains `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` objects, which I thought would be easier to manipulate individually in mpld3 than a `LineCollection`. However, the Plugin seems to be written to deal with a the entire set of red points as a  `Line2D` object (like a polygonal chain with invisible edges, if you see what I mean). This is what I conclude from the fact that the string `'pts'` is used to find the mpld3 id of the points. Just passing a Line2D object to `DragPlugin`, however, does not work:

```
# don't use the suffix:
def __init__(self, object):
        self.dict_ = {"type": "drag","id": utils.get_id(object)}

# after defining `lines` as above:
plugins.connect(fig, DragPlugin(lines[0]))
```

I get the following in the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: obj.elements(...).data(...).style is not a function
```

Which gets raised at the following part of the JS:

```
obj.elements()
           .data(obj.offsets)
           .style("cursor", "default")
           .call(drag);
```

But I have no idea what that JS is doing and it's not documented in the plugin.

Another thing I will need is to restrict the vertical lines to be only draggable horizontally, and conversely for the horizontal lines. But first I would like to get dragging the lines to work at all.

Comment: Have you looked into the [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/) library?  Drop downs, drag, interactive HTML are all part of their game ... and beautiful graphs.

Comment: I did look into it, with search terms like "plotly drag and drop" or "plotly drag element", and didn't immediately find a way to do what I want.

Comment: At this point, the drag functionality is more about shapes and interactive highlighting.  However, there are more mature dropdown selection, slider, etc. interactive features; if that interests you.  Just thought I’d throw it out as an option to you.

Comment: I think I may try something with Plotly sliders. Now that I think of it, I don't strictly need the actual element to be clickable. It's slightly less good but still fine if there's just a slider below that controls it.

Comment: Looks like it may not be possible to have two sliders operating independetly in Plotly. This blog gives the argument for drop-downs and sliders, but the problem is the same: "In both sliders and dropdown menus visibility is boolean mask determining which plots will be visible given pattern. The problem is that sliders mask is independent of dropdown menus’ mask. If you move the slider, sliders’ mask will be activated ignoring the one from dropdown menus and vice versa." https://sylwiamielnicka.com/blog/advanced-plotly-sliders-and-dropdown-menus/#Sliders_Drop-down_menus

Comment: Perhaps one could get around that by overlaying two figures...

Comment: Did you find any new/helpful resources for this?